# Export to CSV file and open in browser

Tags: java, csv, export-to-csv

I am stuck with an issue where I need to export data to a .csv file, but not store the file in file system - instead I need to simply open the file in browser.

I have written the below code to write data to .csv file:

```
FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter("output.csv");
myWriter.append(EmployeeCode);
myWriter.append(',');
myWriter.append(Band);
myWriter.append('\n');
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=output.csv"); 
response.setContentType("application/ms-excel"); 
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

I am able to open a .csv file but it is empty. My data does not get populated into it.
Please suggest what am I doing wrong.

Comment: at the end add `myWriter.flush();myWriter.close();` & while writing print the same data on screen `System.out.println(EmployeeCode + "==" + Band);` and see actually you are getting data or not.

Comment: Fahim,
Yes I am getting the data printed using Sys out.

Comment: @user179516 we should close the file writers to read from the streams at the end :)

Comment: can you add at the end `myWriter.flush();myWriter.close();` and let me know what you get?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`FileWriter` writes the content in the `output.csv` file, not on the response output stream. You should do something like:

```
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
```

To get the response output stream.

And write the content in the `out` stream, something like:

```
response.setContentType("application/ms-excel"); // or you can use text/csv
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=output.csv"); 
try {
    // Write the header line
    OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    String header = "EmployeeCode, Band\n";
    out.write(header.getBytes());
    // Write the content
    String line=new String(EmployeeCode+","+Band+"\n");
    out.write(line.toString().getBytes());
    out.flush();
} catch (Exception e) {
   log.error(e);
}
```